# How to get n random "paragraphs" (groups of ordered lines) from a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, random, awk

I have a file (originally compressed) with a known structure - every 4 lines, the first line starts with the character "@" and defines an ordered group of 4 lines. I want to select randomly n groups (half) of lines in the most efficient way (preferably in bash/another Unix tool).

My suggestion in python is:

```
path = "origin.txt.gz"
unzipped_path = "origin_unzipped.txt"
new_path = "/home/labs/amit/diklag/subset.txt"
subprocess.getoutput("""gunzip -c %s > %s  """ % (path, unzipped_path))
with open(unzipped_path) as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  subset_size = round((len(lines)/4) * 0.5)
  l = random.sample(list(range(0, len(lines), 4)),subset_size)
  selected_lines = [line for i in l for line in list(range(i,i+4))]
  new_lines = [lines[i] for i in selected_lines]
  with open(new_path,'w+') as f2:
    f2.writelines(new_lines)
```

Can you help me find another (and faster) way to do it? 
Right now it takes ~10 seconds to run this code

Comment: Why faster? Is this slow? How slow?

Comment: `subset_size = round((len(lines)/4) * 0.5)` should be after `lines = f.readlines()`

Comment: The `+` in `'w+'` is unnecessary if you write a new file from scratch.

Comment: `4 % 1` is never equal to `1`...

Comment: @LutzHorn - I have ~200 files, each one is a commpressed file (size of ~80 Mb before compressing and has to be unzipped before reading) it takes ~5 seconds to run this code.

Comment: There are some puzzling things in that code. Eg, it defines a list `selected_lines`, which never gets used, and then it attempts to write the nonexistent `new_lines`. Please make sure that the code in the question corresponds to the code you're actually running.

Comment: An https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be useful.  Add a sample file in your question so we can try your code.

Comment: Your code does not select groups, it selects lines. Nothing in your code keeps recognizes groups.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have tried to update my question so it will be easier to understand.
Right now I don't need help on how to "fix" my code, I need to find an alternative to python

Comment: @LutzHorn
I think my edited code is now right (I tried to run it and it worked)

Comment: Is the number of `-`-separated "records" per file known?

Answer (score 0):

The following script might be helpful. This is however, untested as we do not have an example file:

**attempt 1 (`awk` and `shuf`) :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
count=30
path="origin.txt.gz"
new_path="subset.txt"
nrec=$(gunzip -c $path | awk '/^@/{c++}{END print c})'
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1]=1;next}
     !/^@/{next}
     ((++c) in a) { for(i=1;i<=4;i++) { print; getline } }' \
   <(shuf -i 1-$nrec -n $count) <(gunzip -c $path) > $new_path
```

**attempt 2 (`sed` and `shuf`) :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
count=30
path="origin.txt.gz"
new_path="subset.txt"
gunzip -c $path | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/__END_LINE__/g;s/__END_LINE__@/\n@/g' \
   | shuf -n $count | sed 's/__END_LINE__/\n/g' > $new_path
```

In this example, the `sed` line will replace all newlines with the string `__END_LINE__`, except if it is followed by `@`. The `shuf` command will then pick `$count` random samples out of that list. Afterwards we replace the string `__END_LINE__` again by `\n`.

**attempt 3 (`awk`) :**

Create a file called `subset.awk` containing :

```
# Uniform(m) :: returns a random integer such that
#    1 <= Uniform(m) <= m
function Uniform(m) { return 1+int(m * rand()) }

# KnuthShuffle(m) :: creates a random permutation of the range [1,m]
function KnuthShuffle(m,   i,j,k) {
    for (i = 1; i <= m  ; i++) { permutation[i] = i }
    for (i = 1; i <= m-1; i++) {
        j = Uniform(i-1)
        k = permutation[i]
        permutation[i] = permutation[j]
        permutation[j] = k
    }
}

BEGIN{RS="\n@"; srand() }
{a[NR]=$0}
END{ KnuthShuffle(NR);
    sub("@","",a[1])
    for(r = 1; r <= count; r++) {
        print "@"a[permutation[r]] 
     }
}
```

And then you can run :

```
$ gunzip -c <file.gz> | awk -c count=30 -f subset.awk > <output.txt>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :) The second one works but slower than the python code ...

Comment: @diklagelbard I have added a third attempt that might be faster.

Comment: @diklagelbard I also fixed the first case.